# how to use mybatis to group by parameters

Tags: java, mybatis

help...
i want to use mybatis3.2.3 to group by many parameters ,but it doesn't work...please help me.how can i get my answer.thanks.

this is the mappers.

```
<select id="selectByGroup" resultMap="chartMap">                          
    select * from chart group by                                          
    <foreach collection="list" item="item" index="index" separator=",">   
        #{item}                                                           
    </foreach>                                                            
</select>
```

controller:

```
String dims[] = dimension.split(",");

List<String> paraList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String s : dims){
    if(!s.equals(""))
    paraList.add(s);
}

List<Chart> charts = chartDao.selectByMap(paraList);
```

related dao method :

```
public List<Chart> selectByMap(Object obj) {
    List<Chart> chartList = null;
    System.out.println(obj);
    chartList = sqlSession.selectList("draw.selectByGroup",obj);
    return chartList;
}
```

Comment: where is your parameter list to mapper?it have in obj object.?

Answer (score 2):

Just try to replace **#**{item} with **$**{item}.

From the official documentation (http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html):

> **String Substitution**
>
> By default, using the #{} syntax will cause MyBatis to generate
>   PreparedStatement properties and set the values safely against the
>   PreparedStatement parameters (e.g. ?). While this is safer, faster and
>   almost always preferred, sometimes you just want to directly inject a
>   string unmodified into the SQL Statement. For example, for ORDER BY,
>   you might use something like this:
>
> ORDER BY ${columnName} Here MyBatis won't modify or escape the string.
>
> NOTE It's not safe to accept input from a user and supply it to a
>   statement unmodified in this way. This leads to potential SQL
>   Injection attacks and therefore you should either disallow user input
>   in these fields, or always perform your own escapes and checks.